# .jar file not running with arguments

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run a .jar file (named MC) on windows from command and I am using the following code:

```
java -jar MC.jar
```

This works, the file has a UI that pops up and I can change some arguments manually there.

*However*, I want to run this .jar file *without* the UI popping up, and setting the arguments via command line. The file comes with instructions on how to change each parameter. Here is an example:

```
java -jar MC.jar bB 0.004
```

When I try to run this from command line, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at CellSim.main(CellSim.java:113)
```

I have no idea what's going wrong. I should mention I don't know how to code in Java, so I haven't looked at the source code (it would be meaningless to me). I just need to run this .jar file repeatedly and use the output from it (a lot of .csv files).

I should also mention the same .jar file has been used successfully from a Mac and other Windows machines, so this makes me think this is something specific to my PC.

This is what I have installed on my Windows PC: 
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode, sharing)

This is what I have installed on my Mac:
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Please help! I've been looking on the internet for the past 3 hours trying to find a fix.

You can download the .jar file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsjEQyuHtHCLu-nWuNqA3jHlHzWLqevn/view?usp=sharing)

In the images below there are more details about the arguments that can be changed. Note that I have renamed the file to MC.jar.
[Details about the .jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFujc.png)
[Complete list of parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Lhr.png)

Comment: Show us your **code**! If you can't change it, then you can't change how it handles command line arguments.

Comment: I have made the file available now. I was able to change the arguments from command line (on my Mac) so I don't think there's a problem with the code. Maybe I need to install something on my PC?

Comment: "The file comes with instructions on how to change each parameter" - it would be helpful if you provide these instructions as well

Comment: Did the same issue occur in your Mac as well ?

Comment: No, it works as intended on the Mac.

Comment: Issue seems to be with the code.. pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons/cases:

- The properties are not passed into the application (which is you're in doubt about as I understand)
- There is some external that happens in the code that gets executed only if the parameter is indeed passed correctly

If the jar is created properly, the method of passing the arguments is correct, you can be sure about that.

In order to check yourself and practice (and I understand that its a 'student' question), you can print the while args array in a loop right in the method main:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for(String arg : args) {
       System.out.println(arg);
    }  

    // now do your logic here      
}
```

The chances are that you'll see the parameters being printed correctly

So it's probably the second case that you'll have to debug and check what happens there

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Mark. This might well work, however, given my lack of knowledge of programming in Java, debugging this would be like trying to read Chinese.

Comment: With enough time, I have no doubt about it. I'm on a tight schedule with this and I'd like to get it working today. I'm more interested in the data that comes out of this file than the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be in the way it creates output directory.

Here's the decompiled code fragment of the jar file,

[image: decompiled code]

Despite of the OS, variable `path` gets a value which uses '/' as separator.

Eg: path = /C:/mydir/MC.jar

Since File.separator is '\' in windows, it tries to substring using '\' resulting in an exeception in line 113 as it cannot find any occurence of '\' in the path.

So the **bottomline**: The jar file will only run with parameters in Mac/Linux if no modification is done to the code.

Comment: something's wrong here, "getPath" returns a path with "\" (i.e. backslash) separator on windows

Comment: Thank you for getting to the bottom of it. I won't be able to modify the code today since I'd need to actually learn how to code in Java. But it is certainly useful knowing what I have to do when the time comes.

Comment: @mangusta I ran getPath() on windows and I got "/" on windows.

Comment: "getLocation" ran out of my attention here. It returns a "URL" object, and "getPath" called on URL is going to contain slashes only, no matter what the OS is. "getPath" called on File object is going to contain slashes and backslashes depending on OS